# CNN Acc and Loss constant with custom image data

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train a simple CNN model for a binary classification task in Keras with a dataset of images I mined. The problem is that I am getting constant accuracy, val_accuracy and loss after a couple of epochs. Am I processing the data the wrong way? Or is it something in the model settings?

At the beginning I was using softmax as the final activation function and categorical cossentropy, I was also using the to_categorical function on the labels.

After reading up on what usually causes this to happen I decided to use sigmoid and binary_crossentropy instead and not use to_categorical. Still the problem persists and I am starting to wonder whether it's my data the problem (the two classes are too similar) or the way I am feeding the image arrays.

```py
conkeras1 = []
pics = os.listdir("/Matrices/")
# I do this for the images of both classes, just keeping it short.
for x in range(len(pics)):
       img = image.load_img("Matrices/"+pics[x])
       conkeras1.append(img)

conkeras = conkeras1+conkeras2
conkeras = np.array([image.img_to_array(x) for x in conkeras]).astype("float32")
conkeras = conkeras / 255 # I also tried normalizing with a z-score with no success

yecs1 = [1]*len(conkeras1)
yecs2 = [0]*len(conkeras2)

y_train = yecs1+yecs2
y_train = np.array(y_train).astype("float32")

model = Sequential([
Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=conkeras.shape[1:], padding="same", activation="relu"),
Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"),
Flatten(),
Dense(500, activation="relu"),
#Dense(4096, activation="relu"),
Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
             optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
             metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(conkeras, y_train,
                   batch_size=32,
                   epochs=32, shuffle=True,
                   verbose=1,
                   callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

The output I get is this:

```
975/975 [==============================] - 107s 110ms/step - loss: 8.0022 - acc: 0.4800
Epoch 2/32
975/975 [==============================] - 99s 101ms/step - loss: 8.1756 - acc: 0.4872
Epoch 3/32
975/975 [==============================] - 97s 100ms/step - loss: 8.1756 - acc: 0.4872
Epoch 4/32
975/975 [==============================] - 97s 99ms/step - loss: 8.1756 - acc: 0.4872
```

and these are the shapes of the traning set and labels

```
>>> conkeras.shape
(975, 100, 100, 3)
>>> y_train.shape
(975,)
```

Comment: Does ACC stay always around 0.50 for the whole 32 epochs? Since Acc near to 0.5 can be interpreted as some random decision making.  The first guess might be you have done something wrong in creating your training set. Are you sure that task has been done correctly?

Comment: @alift It's exactly the same values from the second or third epoch onward until the 32nd. The training set is made by two groups of images that are barcode-like images, 100 X 100 rgb. The steps in the code are all the steps I have taken in converting the images to arrays, normalizing the values and then feed them to the model.

Comment: I think there are some rooms of improvement in your architecture, but that should not cause the current issue. Have you tried to change a different learning rate? I would go by  0.0001 and 0.001 to see how it goes.